# KCL at bulk in CMOS

Tags: mosfet, bulk-capacitor

This is the circuit:

[image]

[image]

KCL at bulk:

$$V_{out} s C_{bd} + V_{in} s C_{gb} = - V_S s C_{bs} \tag{1}$$

Does this equation work in this case?

KCL at Gate.

$$(V_{in} - V_S) g_m - V_S g_{mb} + \frac{V_{out} - V_S} {r_{ds}}  + V_{out} s C_{bd} + (V_{out} - V_{in}) s C_{gd} = - \frac{V_{out}} {R_D} \tag{2}$$

KCL at Source.
$$(V_{in} - V_S) s C_{gs} + \frac{V_{out} - V_S} {r_{ds}} + (V_{in} - V_S) g_m - V_S g_{mb} - V_S s C_{bs} + (V_{in} - V_S) s C_{gs}= \frac{V_S} {R_S} \tag{3}$$

We have two unkown variables \$V_S\$ and \$V_{out}\$. At the same time,  we also have two equations (1) and (2) here. So we can solve this equation without writing more equation. It looks like \$V_{out}\$ doesn't depend on \$R_S\$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. This is a source degeneration circuit where the gain is approximately \$-\frac{R_D}{\frac{1}{g_m} + R_S} \$, assuming that there is no body effect and channel length modulation.

Comment: @internet Parasitic cap of cmos must be considered. We have to consider those parasitic capacitors since I want accurate MOSFET  level 1 model

Comment: If you want to use the brute force method by writing KCL equations and solving it, just go ahead.  It's not difficult, and you should be able to check your work if there is a mistake.

Comment: @internet I used two equation to solve this \$V_{out}\$, and neither of them has \$R_S\$ inside. That sounds weird. Could you take a look?

Comment: What is the body terminal connected to? The body could be connected to the source or ground in this case. You should write two KCL equations for the source and drain nodes instead.

Comment: @internet The body is grounded.

Comment: The body voltage is already known, why are you writing KCL for the node? As I said above, write KCL for the drain and source nodes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Eq. 1 does not hold because it assumes the body terminal is disconnected. In other words, you are not including current flow from the body terminal to ground when writing KCL. Since this current is not known a priori, writing KCL at the body node is not useful for standard nodal analysis because it requires you to introduce an additional unknown.

All you need to do is write KCL at the source and drain nodes. You will then have two equations that can be solved for the unknown voltages. I don't know how exactly you got Eq. 2 but it doesn't look like either of those equations.

Comment: The second equation is from gate. I doubt there is any current from body to ground because they're the same. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: @kile I don't see how Eq. 2 is KCL at the gate node because some of the terms like \$(V_{out}-V_S)/r_{ds}\$ have nothing to do with the gate node. You also cannot directly apply KCL at the gate node without introducing input current as an unknown variable. Just like the input "voltage source" \$V_{in}\$, the wire connecting bulk to ground (not explicitly shown in your diagrams) is essentially a (0 V) voltage source and can absolutely conduct current. The body is only at ground potential because of this connection.

Comment: @kile All you need to do here is review nodal analysis. There is nothing special about this problem other than that.

Comment: @Puk Sorry. Eq2 is KCL at drain. If you have your way, could you please write your equations in your answer?

Comment: @kile Yes, I see now that your Eq. 2 is KCL at the drain. Your last two equations seem correct, I won't put them in the answer because I'd just be repeating your equations.